# How to mark Jenkins build as failure when any bash step fails

Tags: bash, jenkins

In Jenkinsfile I am creating and running a docker image. In that docker image I have added a bash script as entrypoint.

But even some steps in that bash fails Jenkins shows as build successful. Let's take this example in the below script if the helm update fails I want to show Jenkins build as failed.

```
#!/bin/bash
helm upgrade --install rabbitmq ./rabbitmq/ --namespace rabbitmq
```

Answer (score 1):

You can force the bash scriptlet to stop on error using one of two methods:

1. Explicit Test.
   Add '|| exit 1', after each command
2. Automatic Fail on error
   Add 'set -e' to the top of the bash scriptlet.

Option 1:

```
#! /bin/bash
helm upgrade --install rabbitmq ./rabbitmq/ --namespace rabbitmq || exit 1
...
```

Option 2:

```
#! /bin/bash
set -e
helm upgrade --install rabbitmq ./rabbitmq/ --namespace rabbitmq
...
```